# Populate JQuery Accordion from Entity Framework or SQL Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm new to JQuery and I would like to know if there's a possibility of populating the JQuery Accordion from Entity Framework (preferrably) or an SQL Query. The result set will be used to filter out which items listed in the XML file will be displayed for the logged-in user.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. You will need to build a controller action that will retrieve the filtered items from Entity Framework. You could then return them in a view where the accordion markup is rendered and initialized as a jquery UI accordion.

For example, you could write a controller action that filters a list of pages based on the name of the logged in user:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //retrieve the pages filtered by user
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        IEnumerable<Page> pages = _pageService.FindByUserName(userName);

        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView(pages);
        else
            return View(pages);
    }
```

The view that will be returned from the controller will then render the filtered items in the structure required by the jquery ui accordion. It will also include a piece of javascript code that initializes the accordion (assuming you have already referenced the jquery and jqueryUI scripts in your global layout):

```
@model IEnumerable<Page>

<div id="accordion">
@foreach (var page in Model.Pages)
{
    <h3>@page.Name</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Enter any accordion content here
        </p>
    </div>
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script>
```

Another option would be to return the results from the controller as a JSON if you want to manually perform an AJAX request from the view using jquery. You would then process the returned JSON data so the HTML for the accordion is added to the DOM and finally you would initialize it as a jquery accordion.

The controller would look like:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //retrieve the pages filtered by user
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        IEnumerable<Page> pages = _pageService.FindByUserName(userName);

        return Json(pages, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And the view would be something similar to this:

```
<div id="accordion">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("YourController", "Index")',
           dataType: 'json', 
           success: function(data) {
               var accordionDiv = $("#accordion");
               accordionDiv .empty();
               $.each(data, function(k, v){
                   accordionDiv .append('<h3>' +
                             v.Name + 
                          '</h3>' +
                          '<div><p>' +
                              'Accordion content goes here' +
                          '</p></div>'
                        );
               });                                         
               accordionDiv.accordion(); 
           }              
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So I think it is impossible to do it in the master page right?

Comment: If you follow the first example, then you could include a call to your partial view in the master\layout view. In the case of the second example then you could make that snippet part of the master\layout view.

Comment: Also consider that initally your user will not be logged, so if you make that part of the master\layout view then you will need to consider it on your filtering logic

Comment: Actually, this will happen when the user is logged in.

Comment: If it will only happen when the user is logged in then you should be fine.